# How can I export all attachments from a SharePoint 2010 list without code?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, export, attachments

Is there any solution in exporting all the attachments from a list without code? I do not have Visual Studio installed on my machine and am looking for a way to just grab all the attachments and place them in one location on my hard drive. Can Excel or Access do this? Is there a SharePoint Designer function?

This list is on a SharePoint 2010 site.

Comment: Why not write a powershell script? Code, but no need for visual studio

Comment: I don't have Powershell either.

Answer (score 6):

You can map a drive to the List: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/5216.aspx

The attachments will be under the Attachments folder.

Answer (score 0):

What Robert Lindgren mentioned above - PowerShell would be a good way. Here's an example from a blog post:

[Powershell Script to download attachments on a SharePoint List into a file share](http://bhatiaashish.blogspot.com/2012/08/powershell-script-to-download.html)

Comment: I don't have Powershell installed on my machine either.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use thi link in Internet Explorer, for SharePoint 2013

```
https://Site/Lists/Listutl/AllItems.aspx
```

Go to `List--> Export to Excel`

Comment: please read the question again!