# SP2013 - export custom list attachments with power shell

Tags: powershell, custom-list, export, attachments

I am looking at using powershell to export custom list attachments. Some script help would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [How to use PowerShell to download attachments](http://bhatiaashish.blogspot.in/2012/08/powershell-script-to-download.html)

Also this [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79181/how-can-i-export-all-attachments-from-a-sharepoint-2010-list-without-code) has some details for the same.